# Why would I want to have a non-standard attribute?

Tags: iphone, core-data

The documentation on Core Data entities says:

> You might implement a custom class,
>   for example, to provide custom
>   accessor or validation methods, to use
>   non-standard attributes, to specify
>   dependent keys, to calculate derived
>   values, or to implement any other
>   custom logic.

I stumbled over the non-standard attributes claim. It's just a guess: If my attribute is anything other than NSString, NSNumber or NSDate I will want to have a non-standard Attribute with special setter and getter methods? So, for example, if I wanted to store an image, this would be a non-standard Attribute with type NSData and a special method, say `-(void)setImageWithFileURL:(NSURL*)url` which then pulls the image data from the file, puts in in an NSData and assigns it to core data?

Or did I get that wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-standard attribute can be anything.  Some common examples are:

- an image
- a binary key
- encrypted data
- audio

Just about anything that cannot be represented as a number or string falls into this category.

### update

Transformable is not a data type of it's own.  It is a way to say that a non-standard value is going to be stored here.  Under the covers it is binary.  The Transformable tag is a hint to Core Data to go look at the subclass's property setting.

Comment: Transformables are considered non-standard, too?